# PHP input file error, echo file name with Post method

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to take posted input file name, I'm not uploading anywhere.

I just need the name of posted filename so I'm trying this code;

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo $_FILES['file'];           
}
?>
```

If I change `enctype="multipart/form-data"` into form tag, it's ok, but I need this tag.

Comment: `$_FILES['file']` should be an array, are you getting `array to string` error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You still need the enctype attribute, as the files will not be available without it.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo $_FILES['file']['name'];           
}
```

Comment: yeap, it was easy :) thnks for help. So i can use it a variable. For example;
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];

Comment: sure you can... yw

Answer (score 1):

use

```
echo $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

instead of

```
echo $_FILES['file'];
```

Answer (score 1):

$_FILES['file'] contains array of properties of uploaded file. use print_r instead. It will work fine.
you can get file name like that

> $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];

Answer (score 0):

this code is working fine

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_FILES['file']) ;           
}
?>
```

Comment: its ok but gives me all details of file. "name", "size" etc. I just need name of file. so i can use it a variable later.